# anyway to customise google search such that whenever we click on a link it will automatically create a new tab

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to set up our google page such that whenever we click on a link it will automatically create a new tab instead of navigating to that page?

I'm aware that I can press the Ctrl + click, or right-click + open link in new tab but it would be great if we could customise this behavior (since i find myself opening the links as new tabs like 90% of the times..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a [middle mouse button](http://www.pcworld.com/article/170029/firefox_tip_middleclick_links_to_open_new_tabs.html)? If so, use it!

Comment: wow! i forgot all about it.